# How to put arrays in a struct? (in C)

Tags: c, arrays, struct

So I have two arrays how do I put both in a struct?

The struct will contain more than the array. Do I need to loop to put the values of the array in the struct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [Ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Show your work at least!

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct
{
  int a1[100];
  int a2[10];
} str_arr;

str_arr s1;

s1.a1[0] = 1;
s1.a2[0] = 2;
```

Comment: So literally just putting it in a struct will work?

Comment: Yes. If there is no something specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int    arrayAlpha[10]; // This is an array of ten integers, within a struct
    double arrayBeta[5];   // This is an array of five doubles, within a struct
    char*  text;           // The struct has other elements too.
};
```

Requirements met. 
Would you like to revise your requirements?

Comment: Wow! I feel stupid. I thought I need to manually put it in or something! So literally just put it in a struct will work right?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Show sample code, and describe the exact difficulty and problems you're having.